# Snackbar InflateException

Tags: android, android-snackbar

I was struggling because of studio complaining that `Dialog` is deprecated,
so I went reading the documentation again, seems `Toast` is deprecated too.
So I tried to migrate from `Toast` to `Snackbar`, but fail at the moment...I
i added

```
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
implementation 'com.android.support:design:28.0.0'
```

to my gradle dependencies to get access to the classes needed from the docu.

I wrapped the original `LinearLayout` with a `CoordinatorLayout` changing my main layout to

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
  android:id="@+id/myCoordinatorLayout"
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent">

  <LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:gravity="center">

    <FrameLayout
      android:layout_height="match_parent"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:orientation="vertical"
      android:id="@+id/shellView"
      android:padding="10dp">
   </FrameLayout>
</LinearLayout>
</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

then, in onCreate of the MainActivity i retrieve a reference to that `CoordinatorLayout`

```
 coordinatorView = findViewById(R.id.myCoordinatorLayout);
```

later in `onOptionsItemSelected`, in one of the menu points I am debugging:

```
Snackbar mySnackbar = Snackbar.make(coordinatorView, "Launched import", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG);
mySnackbar.show();
```

as soon as those 2 lines are in, the app crashes:

```
android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #41: Binary XML file line #41: Error         inflating class android.widget.Button
    Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #41: Error inflating class     android.widget.Button
    Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance0(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:334)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:647)
        at         com.android.internal.policy.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:58)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:720)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:788)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:730)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:863)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:824)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:515)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:423)
        at android.support.design.widget.Snackbar.make(Snackbar.java:188)
        at com.nohkumado.nohfibu.MainActivity.onOptionsItemSelected(MainActivity.java:187)
        at android.app.Activity.onMenuItemSelected(Activity.java:3450)
```

which xml file does it take? my main.xml has only 22 lines... and as displayed above, it has no buttons?? the centerview (shellview) is filled by a swappable Fragment that display the actual
functionalty, it starts up with a simple TextView+EditView, so the Startupfragment can't be the culprit too, no buttons there....

so any ideas welcome on how to solve this!

as asked, i add the whole onOptionsItemSelected

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item)
{
FragmentManager fm = getFragmentManager();
Log.d(TAG,"got item clicked "+item.getItemId());

switch (item.getItemId())
    {
  case R.id.menuLsbook:
    Log.d(TAG,"starting up ls book frag");
    LsBookFragment lbook = new LsBookFragment().shell(shell);
    lbook.show(fm, getResources().getString(R.string.mlsbook));
    Log.d(TAG,"ls book running");
    break;
  case R.id.menuShowKpl:
    Log.d(TAG,"starting up kpl frag");

    EditorFrag editorFrag = (EditorFrag) fm.findFragmentByTag(KPLFRAG);
      if(editorFrag == null)
      {
        editorFrag = new EditKplFrag().shell(shell);
      }
      fm.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.shellView,editorFrag,KPLFRAG).commit();
    Log.d(TAG,"kpl running");
    break;
        case R.id.menuShowJrl:
            Log.d(TAG,"starting up jrl frag");

            editorFrag = (EditorFrag) fm.findFragmentByTag(JRLFRAG);
            if(editorFrag == null)
            {
                editorFrag = new EditJrlFrag().shell(shell);
            }
            fm.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.shellView,editorFrag,JRLFRAG).commit();
            Log.d(TAG,"jrl running");
            break;
  case R.id.menu_import:
    Log.d(TAG,"selecting a source for importation of a new book book frag");
    ImportBookFragment ibook = new ImportBookFragment().shell(shell);
    //ibook.show(fm, getResources().getString(R.string.mlsbook));
    Log.d(TAG,"import book running");
    Snackbar mySnackbar = Snackbar.make(coordinatorView, "Launched import", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG);
    mySnackbar.show();

    break;

  case R.id.menu_show_shell:
    Log.d(TAG,"starting shell frag");
    ShellFragment shellfrag = (ShellFragment) fm.findFragmentByTag(SHELLFRAG);
    if (shellfrag == null)
    {
      //Log.d(TAG, "no shell frag");
      shellfrag = new ShellFragment();
      shellfrag.callback(this);
      fm.beginTransaction().add(R.id.shellView, shellfrag, SHELLFRAG).commit();
      //Log.d(TAG, "shellfrag added");
      if(shell != null) shellfrag.shell(shell);
    }//if (shellfrag == null)
    shell = shellfrag.shell();
    Log.d(TAG,"shell displaying");
    break;


  case R.id.menu_settings:
            Log.d(TAG, "case is settings, creating intent");
            //Intent intent = new Intent();
            //intent.setClassName(this, "com.nohkumado.nohfibu.SettingsActivity");
            Intent intent = new Intent(this, SettingsActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
            //startActivityForResult(i, RESULT_SETTINGS);
            Log.d(TAG, "fired intent");
            break;
        case R.id.mabout:
            AboutDialogFragment about = new AboutDialogFragment();
            about.setVersion(new VersionCommand(shell).execute());
            about.show(fm, getResources().getString(R.string.mabout));
            break;
  case R.id.menu_manual:
    about = new AboutDialogFragment();
    about.setVersion(new VersionCommand(shell).execute());
    about.show(fm, getResources().getString(R.string.empty));
    break;
    }

    return true;
}
```

Comment: Are you adding any action to your `snackbar`?

Comment: no, at the moment i just to replace the Toast by a Snackbar....

Answer (score 0):

> Binary XML file line #41: Error inflating class
>   android.widget.Button

It's coming from `Button` class. **However**,

Add:

```
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
```

To your `build.gradle` dependencies then try.

You won't need :

```
implementation 'com.android.support:coordinatorlayout:28.0.0-alpha1'
```

**Update:** After checking your added codes, it seems like you are actually trying to show `Fragment`s inside `LinearLayout` with `shellView` id. Change it to `FrameLayout` then it should work I hope.

Comment: changed the implementation to appcompat, thought that i include only the really needed stuff... but well, rebuild, rerun, same error? still hanging up on Button...

Comment: Studio doesn't like that sort of casts, removes them when i do a code analysis, but well, added it, doesn't change anything :(

Comment: Just checked your codes. The interesting part is you don't have `Button` in your layout or even in java side. However, you are trying to show fragments inside `LinearLayout`. `-> shellView`. Change it to `FrameLayout` then try.

Comment: is FrameLayout better as a placeholder for Fragments? well changed, everthing else works, but the snackbar still produces the same crash....

Comment: `FrameLayout` is the best options in this case. How about commenting it then checking if it works without `SnakeBar`? Perhaps there is some problem with imports in `SnakeBar`? You can easily check by commenting the `SnakeBar` to see if that causes the issue. Also, check the imports too, That's pretty rare and weird!

Comment: all fine when Snackbar stuff is ocmmented... well... thanks for the try, will have to revert using Toasts....

Comment: Cool, so the problem is `SnakeBar`. Let's find out what causes the issue. Try with this: `Snackbar.make(findViewById(android.R.id.content), "Launched import", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)` and the rest. Also, rebuild-delete caches might help too.

Comment: nope, still the same, in the meantime, with https://github.com/commonsguy/cwac-crossport it works! still would be better to use the original....

Comment: Of course, this can be a bug too. However, what about your fragments layouts? Did you check them? That would be great to see your whole dependencies + fragments layouts to resolve this issue.

Comment: that's a lot :D but as sayd the starting fragment only has a TextView and an EditText.... ok, pause till tomorrow...

Comment: It shouldn't actually happen. I'm suspecting about dependencies or, a typo mistake. Otherwise, that's a bug. Interesting BTW.